# Is it possible to create a TransactionScope in a Custom WCF Service Behavior? (async, await, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, async-await, transactionscope

## TL;DR ?

Screencast explaining problem: https://youtu.be/B-Q3T5KpiYk

## Problem

When flowing a transaction from a client to a service **Transaction.Current** becomes **null** after **awaiting** a service to service call.

Unless of course you create a new TransactionScope in your service method as follows:

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
public async Task CallAsync()
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        await _service.WriteAsync();
        await _service.WriteAsync();            
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Why TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption isn't enabled by default I don't know, but I don't like to repeat myself so I figured I'd always create an inner transactionscope with that option using a custom behavior.

### Problem UPDATE

It doesn't even have to be a service to service call, an await to a local async method also nulls Transaction.Current. To clearify with an example

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
public async Task CallAsync()
{
    await WriteAsync();
    // Transaction.Current is now null
    await WriteAsync();                     
}
```

## Attempted Solution

I created a Message Inspector, implementing IDispatchMessageInspector and attached it as a service behavior, code executes and everyting no problem there, but it doesn't have the same effect as declaring the transactionscope in the service method.

```
public class TransactionScopeMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        var transactionMessage = (TransactionMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["TransactionMessageProperty"];
        var scope = new TransactionScope(transactionMessage.Transaction, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);            
        return scope;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        var transaction = correlationState as TransactionScope;
        if (transaction != null)
        {
            transaction.Complete();
            transaction.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

by looking at the identifiers when debugging I can see that it in fact is the same transaction in the message inspector as in the service **but**
after the first call, i.e.

```
await _service_WriteAsync();
```

**Transaction.Current** becomes **null**. Same thing if not getting the current transaction from **OperationContext.Current** in the message inspector as well so it's unlikely that is the problem.

## Question

Is it even possible to accomplish this? It appears like the only way is to declare a TransactionScope in the service method, that is:

```
public async Task CallAsync()
{
    var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
    await _service.WriteAsync();
    await _service.WriteAsync();            
    scope.Complete();
}
```

with the following service contract it's obvious that we get an exception on the second service call if transaction.current became null inbetween

```
[OperationContract, TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]
Task WriteAsync();
```

Comment: Found [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pm3gCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT742&ots=nbt7EaxsJw&dq=wcf%20TransactionScopeRequired%20async&pg=PT742#v=onepage&q=wcf%20TransactionScopeRequired%20async&f=false) it looks like it poses the exact same question you are asking and provides some solutions, unfortunately the solutions are not fully available due to the link being a preview of the book.

Comment: It describes the problem exactly, the conclusion is basically that it can't be done in a clean way. Quoting the book: "We consider the lack of parity with standard WCF behavior introduces by async service operations a design flaw of WCF...". And then a far from ideal / insane solution is proposed. I'll stick to manually creating an inner transactionscope until I find something better. Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out we shouldn't really be using the async/await keyword on the server together with distributed transactions, see [this blog post](http://www.towfeek.se/2016/03/connection-leaks-when-using-asyncawait-with-transactions-in-wcf/) for details.