# TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption does not flow from WCF client to service

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

My WCF service method needs to perform concurrent tasks in a transaction which is flowed from the client to service. To enable a transaction scope to flow through threads, I enabled the TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption in the constructor of transaction scope class before sending call to service.

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    //service call here. Async flow option has no effect on service side.
}
```

The transaction flows from client to service but it is not able to flow to sub tasks. If, however, I create new transaction scope in the service and enable its async flow there, then transaction flows to sub tasks. So my question is, why the TransactionScopeAsyncFlow option has no effect on the transaction at the service end? Should not it take the client transaction scope settings so there would not be any need to create new transaction scope in service just to enable its async flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767978/is-it-possible-to-create-a-transactionscope-in-a-custom-wcf-service-behavior-a) as well. What actually happens is that WCF loses nearly all of its context upon crossing the threshold of first await and we should explicitly opt-in to flow any ambient context such as ambient transaction to subsequent async calls. There are some workarounds mentioned in [this](https://books.google.com.bh/books?id=Pm3gCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT742&ots=nbt7EaxsJw&dq=wcf%20TransactionScopeRequired%20async&pg=PT742&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=wcf%20TransactionScopeRequired%20async&f=false) book. Check them out if you need more detail. I'll go with creating new scope before async call in the service operation.